# query through populated field in mongo

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to query through the populated field. In this case, the populated field is reviews. So if my searched query matches the reviews tables description field... then return that book. Reviews is an array of objects and description is one of the keys in it.

I have tried using reviews[0].description in the query object but it didn't work.

```
getBookInfo: (req, res) => {
        const search = req.params.search;
        const query = { $or: [{ title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } }] };
        Books.find(query).populate('reviews').exec(function(err, books) {
            if (err) {
                return err;
            }
            return books;
        });
    }
```

Comment: So You're searching in reviews not in books. Am I correct?

Comment: @num8er yes i want to search in both. So books field would be title and then also search the description from reviews

Comment: so you have a book schema with `title` and `description` as attributes right ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey yes that is correct. In the books schema... i have title, description, and reviews(its a reference to the reviews table). In the reviews table, i have title and description as well

Comment: `find( { $or: [ { title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } } ,{reviews: {$elemMatch: {description:{ $regex: search, $options: 'i' }}}}] } )` ??

Comment: @GeorgeBailey You're correct if reviews are kept in books collection document. But in example is used populate that means books collection keep review id-s in reviews. So You cannot query objectid-s for description field.

Comment: yeah. Didn't know that.  Sorry for misunderstanding the question

Comment: @GeorgeBailey in my experience it's better to build some index of reviews with book's necessary fields in it. It can be some collection/model `ReviewsIndex` or it can be ElasticSearch index to not make high load on mongodb

Comment: Yes that's what mostly used and appreciated. I totally agree

Comment: @HeelMega I think You should create `BookSearchIndex` model and every-time when user write review additionally insert to that collection document that keep the `book` and `value` fields, where book is reference, and value is concatenation of `book.title + book.description + review.title + review.description` and when You do search for book, just do query to that index collection and retrieve Your book. Or just move something that helps easily do relational queries.

Comment: The question nominated to be duplicate. But it's incorrect. I don't know how it can be nominated to be duplicate of question that works with small data (`tags`) vs unlimited amount of data (`reviews`) ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for books and populate reviews that does match for Your query.

So by [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) You've right to use `match` for population.

Here You go:

```
getBookInfo: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const search = req.params.search;

    // query for books matching by condition
    const query = { 
      $or: [
        { title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
        { description: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
      ] 
    };

    // include reviews matching by conditions
    const include = {
      path: 'reviews',
      match: {
        description: { 
          $regex: search, 
          $options: 'i' 
        }
      },
      options: {limit: 5}
    };

    const books = await Books
                          .find(query)
                          .populate(include)
                          .lean();
    res.status(200).send(books);
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

UPDATE:

As I understand You want to query both review and book.

1. have `book` field in Review model that will keep book `_id`, `title` and `description`.
2. when user add's a review just put that book data into review document.
3. query directly reviews collection.

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: @HeelMega I've added some comment under Your question. You've to build some index collection. Mongodb does not allow such complex queries.

Comment: yea i was thinking that is the way to go

Comment: @HeelMega or if You're at the beginning of path, switch to MySQL, Postgres and as ORM use Sequelize

Comment: Now... I got the _id's of all the reviews in a big array. How do I put them in my query because its an array not just a string

Comment: @HeelMega like this: `Book.find({_id: arrayOfIds});` or just define reference in index model and `populate('book')`